# javafx table не отображаются данные

Tags: java, javafx

Здравствуйте.Пытаюсь отобразить в таблице данные но почему то не выходит. Вот код

```
public class TableController implements Initializable {
    private ObservableList<Event> events= FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    @FXML
    private TableView<Event> tableView=new TableView<>();
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Event, Integer> idColumn=new TableColumn<>();
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Event, String> dateColumn=new TableColumn<>();
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Event, String> textColumn=new TableColumn<>();

    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {     
        textColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("event"));            
        Event event1= new Event (1, 11111, "Один");
        Event event2= new Event (2, 22222, "Два");
        Event event3= new Event (3, 33333, "Три");
        events.add(note0);
        events.add(note1);
        events.add(note2);
        events.add(note3);
        tableView.setItems(events);
    }
}

public class Event{
    private int id;
    private long date;
    private String event;

    public Event(int id, long date, String note) {
        this.id = id;
        this.date = date;
        this.event= event;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public long getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public String getEvent() {
        return event;
    }
}
```

Итак, как видно я список я добавил 3 элемента, они то и должны отобразится в таблице, но не отображаются, подскажите в чем может быть дело?

Comment: А откуда взялись переменные note0..note3?

Answer (score 1):

Как оказалось я использовал в fxml id вместо fx:id.Вопрос считаю решенным.